# can JSTL be used with SVG tags?

Tags: html, jsp, svg, jstl

Im trying to draw a bar graph using SVG tags, this is the tag that creates one of the bars

`<g class="g" transform="translate(17,0)">
<s:rect width="15" y="110" height="340" style="fill: rgb(152, 171, 197);"></s:rect>
</g>`

can JSTL be used to replace the height value with information from a Database? I was able to do a query succesfuly using the `<sql:setDataSource> <sql:query>` tags, but if I try to insert JSTL in the svg it doesn't work, I tried something like this.

`<c:forEach var="bar" begin="0"
            items="${result.rowsByIndex}">`

`<g class="g" transform="translate(17,0)">
<s:rect width="15" y="110" height="${bar[3]}" style="fill: rgb(152, 171, 197);"></s:rect>
</g>`

`</c:forEach>`

doing it outside the svg worked fine.

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens precisely?

Comment: It doesn't draw the rectangle at all I also tried to add <c:out value="${bar[3]}"/> in the height value, but it didn't work either

Comment: Is the rectangle in the DOM?

Comment: Its inside an <svg> tag in the body of the JSP

Comment: What does the tag library "s" do?